Who to believe?: Attic mold/roofing advice
Background:

Two years ago: I noticed that the roof plywood in my walk up attic had moisture. There are stairs going to a storage room with pony walls (in here the insulation is right on the plywood), as well as standard attic space on either side of the pony walls. A look inside the pony walls (i.e., not in the storage space) showed there was mold there. The action I took was contacting an attic company and they told me that it was an insulation issue. Completely re-insulated the attic and remediated the mold. The company offered a 5 year warranty.

One Year Ago:  I noticed that the plywood was wet again. And the
mold was back too. The company that I initially hired came out and
said it was a lack of ventilation. So they (a) remediated the mold
(b) installed some more roof vents.

A Week or So Ago: I noticed that
the moisture issues are not solved. I suspect the mold is back too.
So instead of just trusting the attic company I initially hired, I
have had roofing companies, attic companies, and mold specialists
come out. I need to fix this issue once and for all! The issue is
that there were some consistencies and inconsistencies with what I
was told about fixing the issue (see below).


What was consistent was...

I need a new roof. The previous owners did a bad job and I have photos on the roof there there are starting to be problems. And there are some leaks that could be contributing to the water issues, though it sounds like this isn't the whole story.
The air circulation sucks. The company I hired appears to have cut holes randomly in my roof to improve circulation. It doesn't work like that. There needs to be intake lower on the roof or near the soffit and a way for air to exit near the top of the roof.
The walk up portion of the attic, should we want to finish it with some drywall to make a little office space, should be insulated with spray foam. We'll probably take this route eventually.

What we're getting mixed signals on is when and how to address the mold/insulation...

A mold expert suggested we simply reroof the house and add the proper ventilation (which the house doesn't currently have). He then suggested that we wait several months to make sure that the moisture in the attic drops so that we're convinced that the issue has been addressed. And once things are good and dry, then we can remediate the mold, do the insulation work if desired etc. He also said the company we originally hired showed they don't understand remediation of mold or how airflow should work in an attic :(
A GC that specializes in attics suggested that we prioritize airflow as suggested above when we reroof the house, but he also suggested that we immediately prioritize taking care of the mold and getting the right insulation in place ASAP. While it sounds bad to leave mold untreated, a company that specialized in mold (see the above bullet) suggested we wait a few months and that remediating when it's not all dried out would be bad. So I'm not sure who to believe.

Based on all of this background, can anyone advise on how they would proceed with our house? I really need to fix this once and for all and I am struggling figuring out who to believe!

Assuming you're in the USA, which state?

In Washington State

Why is everyone so paranoid about mold on here? Your roof is leaking. Get someone to fix your roof, worry about your office, stairwell later

Listen to @RMDman

Number one you need to replace the roof.  Or at the least repair the leaks.
Anyone telling you that it needs to be repaired is telling the truth. There would not be mould without moisture and that is coming from the roof leaks.
After the roof leaks are fixed, or the roof replaced, with proper ventilation, address the mold issue. The mold experts were telling the truth. There is no logical reason to remediate if the cause of the problem is not corrected. ( Understand mold can be dangerous, but it is not radioactive and has to be removed as if it is.)
The guy telling you to wait to remediate is telling the truth. Otherwise you will be calling him back to do his job again and blaming him for the regrowth of the mold.

Yeah, the roof leaks are obviously causing the mold.  This isn't rocket surgery.

Moisture in the attic could very well be condensation from humid air coming up from living spaces. For that matter, moisture could be condensing on cold attic surfaces from ordinary outside ventilation air, which in the Pacific Northwest is close to being saturated for about half the year. In those parts, a tight roof will in no way prevent dampness and rust and mildew in attics.

Except the OP stated that they had roof leaks.
